# select_tag sitting outside user params?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Afternoon All,

Been trying to figure out where this is coming from but cannot understand why I get the following, here is my select_tag.

```
<%= select_tag :area_of_focus, options_for_select(User::LANGUAGES), {multiple: true, include_blank: false} %>
```

Here is the constant:

```
 LANGUAGES = ["Rails", "Ruby", "Javascript", "C#", "HTML", "CSS", "SQL" ]
```

When I run the submit on update I get the following validation error on area_of_focus. First this is from the rails console log,

```
"area_of_focus"=>["Javascript"]
```

and this is from the debug on my page:

```
area_of_focus: ! '["Javascript"]'
```

UPDATE: Just noticed that my params listed below, :area_of_focus is sitting outside the user hash:

```
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"ZAAObfDDIUumIJV2cQjkZSkaUY6RsHbdFY1MEd28hvI=", "user"=>{"company_name"=>"kdkdsh", "street"=>"ksakjakjs", "city"=>"kjsdkjskds", "state"=>"kdjsksksj", "postcode"=>"ksdjkssk", "employer_desc"=>"kdjskksdhdsjs", "number_of_employees"=>"100", "email"=>"shaun@shaun1.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]", "current_password"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "area_of_focus"=>["Ruby", "Javascript"], "commit"=>"Update"}
```

What have I done incorrectly here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try: `<%= form.select :area__of_focus, ....`

Comment: such a dumb mistake !